# Google Query - "NOT LIKE" Statement Doesn't work

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

The following line doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(AB:AE,"select AB,AC,AD,AE where AB NOT LIKE '%Info%'",1)
```

Throws:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "AH "" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "("

However, this one does:

```
=QUERY(AB:AE,"select AB,AC,AD,AE where AB LIKE '%Info%'",1)
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? I suspect that it merely doesn't do what you expect, because you don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "AH "" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

NOT should be before column identifier:

```
=QUERY(AB:AE,"select AB,AC,AD,AE where NOT AB LIKE '%Info%'",1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably column `AB` is nullable:

```
=QUERY(AB:AE,"select AB,AC,AD,AE where AB NOT LIKE '%Info%' OR AB IS NULL",1)
```

[The Three-Valued Logic of SQL](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic)

```
AB + (NOT AB) + (NULL in column AB) <=> entire set
```

Comment: Tried this:=QUERY(AH:AK,"select AH,AI,AJ,AK where AH NOT LIKE '%Info%' OR AH IS NULL",1)  and still getting this error:  Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "AH "" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...